# When Tiling Background Image -> Set Background Multiple Of Tile?

Tags: css

**Simple Square Image Tile Example:** *- 49x50px*

[image: Square black bordered image 49x50px]

**Tiling This Image** *- 125x50px container example*

[image: Simple Black Square Repeated Y in 125x50px container example]

**Question:**

Using CSS only, is it an attribute or any other means to set a container with an auto height attribute of auto to be a rounded up multiple of the background image height to ensure the tile is not cut off?

**Why / My Usage:**

One of my usages is to have a scroll. The top and bottom all fancy and old looking whereas the middle will be an image repeated on the y-axis, however if there is not a perfect match at the bottom, it *can* result in a noticeable line loosing the effect of one image / container!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to use the background-repeat property

```
.container {
  background-image: url(URL_HERE);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

That will tile the background image in the y axis as many times as it can to fill the element

Comment: I think you've misunderstood @lynch. This will produce the cut example container image provided in my question whereas I want to ensure the container is a rounded up multiple of the background image size. Whereas my image provided is 49x50px, if the auto height reached 125px the height would be set to 147px to ensure no tile cutting.

Comment: Oh I see! As far as I know there isn't any such property, as CSS doesn't perform calculations etc. You'd probably need some sort of JavaScript script that forces the height of the container to a multiple of the height of the background image

Comment: Yeah I was thinking this, set height to auto, floor(check height / tile size) != 0 then number + 1 x tile hight.... I was hoping there was some CSS I didn't know about such as "tile-height' or whatnot!

Comment: None that I've ever heard of I'm afraid, looks like JS is your answer!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not do that with CSS.

You can, however, do the opposite: adjust the image to the dimension of the container

```css
.test {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 14px 0px 0px;
-moz-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 round;
-webkit-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 round;
-o-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 round;
border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 fill round;
}

#test1 {
  width: 100px;
}

#test2 {
  margin-top: 80px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="test1"></div>
<div class="test" id="test2"></div>
```

This is achieved with the round style of the border image property

That would set all 4 borders of the image, but I have set the other borders to dimesion 0, so all you get is a stripe of the image tiled, and adjusted to fit

See [border image generator](http://border-image.com/#%7B%22src%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FTR%2Fcss3-background%2Fborder.png%22%2C%22linkBorder%22%3Afalse%2C%22borderWidth%22%3A%5B14%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%22imageOffset%22%3A%5B27%2C27%2C27%2C27%5D%2C%22fill%22%3Atrue%2C%22setRepat%22%3Afalse%2C%22repeat%22%3A%5B%22round%22%2C%22round%22%5D%2C%22scaleFactor%22%3A3%2C%22setRepeat%22%3Atrue%7D) to see it alive.

Also, see it applied to an example similar to the one in your question. hover to div to see the image adapting to the size

```css
.test {
    width: 50px;
    height: 125px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 4s;
}
.test:hover {
    height: 400px;
}

.test:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border-left-width: 50px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-image-source: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png);
    border-image-slice: 27;
    border-image-repeat: round;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: It is not the border I am looking for, it is the inner unspecified height however thank you for your feedback @Vals

Comment: Yes, I know, but most probably it can be adapted. (difficult to say for sure because you don't give your code, but maybe using a pseudo element). Of course, it can be use for any direction horizontal or vertical